# Stop receiving friend's status updates as notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, iphone

I'm having problems with Facebook since the latest update (subscriptions, I think.)  On the web application, I now receive status updates from certain friends as notifications.  I don't need to see them as notifications because I can see them plain as day on my news feed.

This is particularly a problem in iPhone.  My iPhone stated this morning I had 6 notifications, but when I opened the notifications, there were no new ones.  The iPhone counts them like the web application does, but only displays notifications for comments, likes, etc.

I'm sick of seeing false notifications.  How can I prevent Facebook from creating notifications from status updates?

Comment: See also [Facebook's FAQ on this question.](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=112320895539157)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Never mind, I finally found the setting.

1. Press the **Facebook** logo to the Facebook Home page.
2. On the left-hand side, under **Lists**, press **Close Friends**.  You may need to press **More** first.
3. In the top-right corner, press the **Notifications** button and select **Off**.

So they hid the option in a place that usually never contains options.  How ever so intuitive... </rant>

Comment: Thank You!!!!! How obvious that should be.. I never thought to try that way though!

Comment: I'm not on "timeline", so the accepted answer didn't work for me.  

I had to:
* click on my name in the top left
* click on "friends" on the left panel
* scroll through friends until I found my "close friend" as specified by the <kbd>close friend</kbd> button on the right
* click on the selected "close friend" label to deselect it

The <kbd>close friend</kbd> should now be demoted to simply <kbd>friend</kbd> as specified by the button on the right.

Comment: As of 2017, this no longer works unfortunately. Even with "Close Friends Notifications" OFF, you will still get notifications about friends updating status, sharing pics, etc. The only way I have found to get rid of them is to *unfollow* them. This take them off your feed though as well.... so if you want to see a friend's posts in your feed then you HAVE to get notifications when they update something, meaning you MUST follow them. Facebook BLOWS.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2021 Oct

You can go to Settings → Notifications → Updates From Friends and turn it off
[image]